# codeigniter update database with "TRUE" for checked items and "FALSE" for remaining unchecked items

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to php/codeignitor and trying to post changes on form checkboxes to my db. The row to modify is assigned by the gl_id below. 
I am not sure how to use my update_checked function in the model to
post TRUE to each of these fields where gl_id =x and FALSE using to the remaining fields not in the array. I can create and view the array of checked values using $_POST['checked'] in the controller
and passing it to the model. Now I need to use this array to post to the db where gl_id = the value from the form in the view.

In View

```
    <h1>Update GL id <?php echo $gl_field['gl_id'];?></h1>
        <label>Stat</label>
            <input type="checkbox" <?php if ($gl_field['stat'] == "TRUE") {echo "checked = checked";} ?>   
            name = "checked[]" id="stat" value= "stat"  /><BR CLEAR="all">
        <label>Exclude</label>
            <input type="checkbox" <?php if ($gl_field['exclude'] == "TRUE") {echo "checked = checked";} ?>  
            name="checked[]" id="exclude" value= "exclude"><BR CLEAR="all">
        <label>Override</label>
            <input type="checkbox" <?php if ($gl_field['override'] == "TRUE") {echo "checked = checked";} ?>          
            name= "checked[]" id= "override" value = "override"/><BR CLEAR="all">
```

In Controller

```
            public function update_table(){
               $this->load->helper('form');
               $this->page_nav_model->update_table();
               $checked_array = $_POST['checked'];
               $this->page_nav_model->update_checked($checked_array);
               $this->load->view('pages/success');
            }
```

In Model

```
    foreach($checked_array as $true){
            echo $true;                             
        }
```

To clarify when I pull the information into the form in the example above all of the checkboxes are set to "TRUE" in the db so they are checked. If I uncheck stat and click submit I am able to see an array with the values (exclude, override).

I appreciate any help that sets me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update your table with CI all at once, you need an array like this:

```
    $data = array(
        'column_1_name' => 'value_to_insert'
        'column_2_name' => 'value_to_insert'
        'column_2_name' => 'value_to_insert'
    );
```

Right now, you have an array like this $checked_array = ('stat', 'exclude', 'override') - with more or fewer members.

To create the array that you can use in your update statement (like $data above), what you need to do is create another array with the name of each column and a value equal to 1 if it is in $checked_array or 0 if it was not in $checked array.

The function add_values() below can do that for you. You have to supply two arguments:

1. $all_possibilities is an array of each column name that you will want to update to either 1 or 0. In this case, it should look like $all_possibilities = array('stat', 'exclude', 'override');
2. $selected: this is an array with the names of the boxes that were actually selected - it is a subset of $all_possibilities (or it is the same if all the boxes were checked).

This function goes in your controller.

```
    function add_values($all_possibilities, $selected) {

        $array_for_query = array();
        // this goes through each possible box that can be checked to see if that possibility was actually selected
        foreach($all_possibilities as $array_member) {
            // this checks to see if the current member of $all_possibilities is found in the $selected array
            if (in_array($array_member, $selected)) {
                    // if it is, it adds that as a member of a new query $array_for_query and gives it a value of 1 (true)
                    $array_for_query[$array_member] = 1;
                } else {
                    // if it is not, same as above, but gives it a value of 0
                    $array_for_query[$array_member] = 0;        
                }
        }

        // once all the possibilities have been checked and added to the query array, that array is returned
        return $array_for_query;
    }
```

Now you can call the function and pass the two arguments in. The returned array is assigned to $checked_and_unchecked.

```
    $data['checked_and_unchecked'] = add_values($possibilities, $checked_array);
```

Make sure you also grab the gl_id from the form. You can do that with a hidden field in your view:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="gl_id" value="<?php echo $gl_field['gl_id'];?>" />
```

In the controller, grab that value with

```
    $data['gl_id'] = $this->input->post('gl_id');
```

Then you can pass the information to your model and update your table passing in the name of the table and the array you created.

```
    $this->model_name->model_method($data);
```

This will then go in the model:

```
    $this->db->update('table_name', $checked_and_unchecked);
    $this->db->where('gl_id', $gl_id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and function Tayler. It is working great!

Answer (score 0):

If a checkbox is unchecked in the HTML, the value does not get sent via $_POST. This is not accounted for in CodeIgniter. This is how I deal with this issue. In the controller:

```php
/**
 * Set post values for unchecked boxes.
 *
 * @access private
 * @return void
 */
private function _section_checkboxes()
{
    if (!$this->input->post('is_active')) {$_POST['is_active'] = 0;}
    // other checkboxes here...
}

/**
 * if form validation passes, run this to edit a section
 *
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */
public function do_edit_section()
{
    $this->_section_checkboxes();
    if ($this->section_model->edit_section($this->input->post()))
    {
        redirect('success_page');
    }
}
```

And in the model:

```php
/**
 * updates a section with active record, returns success.
 * 
 * @access public
 * @param array $data
 * @return bool
 */
public function edit_section(array $data)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $data['id']);
    return $this->db->update('sections', $data);
}
```

And in the view, using the form helper:

```php
<?=form_checkbox(array('name' => 'is_active', 'id' => 'is_active_field', 'value' => '1', 'checked' => (bool)$item->is_active))?>
```

Now your unchecked checkboxes are set as 0 when unchecked, 1 when checked. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: You're welcome! [Here's a helper](https://gist.github.com/4004986) to make it even easier

Answer (score 0):

So I still needed help getting the final touches on the overall project so I wanted to post the final results here for anyone as green as I looking to control checkboxes from the db and the db from checkboxes.

Controller:

```
    [function from Tayler and]
    $all_checkbox_fields = array('stat','exclude','override');  
        $checked_array = $_POST['checkbox'];
        $data['checkbox'] = $this->add_values($all_checkbox_fields, $checked_array); 
        $data['gl_id'] = $this->input->post('gl_id');
        $this->page_nav_model->update_checked($data); 
        $this->load->view('pages/success');
```

Model:

```
    public function update_checked($data){
        $this->default_db->where('gl_id', $data['gl_id']); 
        $this->default_db->update('oracle_table', $data['checkbox']); 
    }
```

View:

```
    <label>Stat</label>
        <input type="checkbox" <?php if ($gl_field['stat'] == "1") {echo "checked = checked";} ?>   
        name = "checkbox[]" id="stat" value= "stat"/><BR>
    <label>Exclude</label>
        <input type="checkbox" <?php if ($gl_field['exclude'] == "1") {echo "checked = checked";} ?>  
        name="checkbox[]" id="exclude" value= "exclude"/><BR>
    <label>Override</label>
        <input type="checkbox" <?php if ($gl_field['override'] == "1") {echo "checked = checked";} ?>          
        name= "checkbox[]" id= "override" value = "override" ><BR>
```